# Find a div in Flexslider after callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flexslider

I'm using [Flexslider](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/wiki/FlexSlider-Properties). On completing each slide, I want to find the content of a div `.extra`. I'm trying to use the `after` callback function of Flexslider to find the content of the div, but it does not find. It does not even find any parent or any other element class.

How can I find the content of `.extra` div on completing each slide?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="extra">abc</div>
    <div class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li><img src="image1.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="image2.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="image3.jpg" /></li>    
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    after: function(slider) {
        var abc = $(this).parents().find('.extra').html();
        alert(abc);
    }
});
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/he8gfh29/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will work for you :) as the slider's selector is being passed through `function(slider)` you need to use `slider` object at the place of `$(this)`.

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    after: function(slider) {
        var abc = slider.parents().find('.extra').html();
        alert(abc);
    }
  });
```